# Access cloud sharing files in dropbox, google drive, microsoft onedrive etc. in android app

Tags: android, dropbox-api, onedrive

I have a Windows desktop software that can save a file with customer phone numbers at a dropbox/onedrive/google drive path etc. Can I access that file programatically file on android from any cloud storage? because all customer data is entered in Windows desktop software, but need to send SMS to customers from an Android app. So, I have to somehow share data from Windows desktop software with the Android app. So, either I can programatically share files between Windows desktop and Android using cloud storage.

If not then I will have to develop a web service that will be accessed by both Windows desktop software and android app for data sharing.

Or there any better way to share data?

Answer (score 1):

There are android sdk's for all of the three example cloud storage solutions you provide.

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/android)

[Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro)

[OneDrive](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android)

With those you can access your file from your android app.